# How to make sure that two csv files have the same columns in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a csv file, let's call it file1.csv. When I read a new file, say file2.csv, I want to first perform a check that all of the columns in file1.csv which is basically the format I expect for my data are present in file2.csv.

file2.csv may have additional columns but I want to construct my data set such that it is basically trimmed down to the columns present in file1.csv.

How can I do this?

EDIT : 
@user1436187 , sorry I wasn't thinking about %in%. I was able to do using it

```
if(length(which(names(df2)%in% names(df1))) == length(names(df1)))
{
 cat(paste("df2 contains all columns in df1"))
}else
{
 cat(paste("df2 does not contain all columns in df1"))
}
```

Comment: You can read them to R with `read.csv` and check the columns with `match` or `%in%`. What is the problem!

Comment: Do you want to check if they have the same class?  Some examples would be helpful.  `dat2New <- dat2[names(dat1)]`

Comment: @akrun, thanks akrun, Nope, Just wanted to check if columns are present. And thanks for the one liner, really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all the columns in 'dat1' are present in 'dat2', you can just subset the 'dat2' based on the column names from 'dat1'

```
 dat2New <- dat2[names(dat1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you import entire files, this is one way of doing it.

```
file1 <- data.frame(a = runif(5), b = runif(5), c = runif(5))
file2 <- data.frame(d = runif(5), e = runif(5), a = runif(5), b = runif(5), c = runif(5))

file2 <- file2[, names(file2) %in% names(file1)] # file2 now has only columns present in file1
# file2 <- file2[, names(file1)] # this would also work
```

Another way of doing things would be to import only the first line of the file to get column names, do a similar operation using `%in%` and then importing only specific columns from `file2` using argument `colClasses` in `read.table` and kin.

Comment: `file2[intersect(names(file2),names(file1))]` as a variation.